# Is there a power series that converges to the function $f(x)= \lvert x\rvert$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Is there a power series that converges to the function $f(x)= \lvert x\rvert$ for all $x$?

I am pretty lost on how to even start this.

Comment: No. This function is not even differentiable at $0$, while power series give us functions that are infinitely differentiable within their interval of convergence.

Comment: You can however approximate it by a sequence of smooth functions: $$f_n=\sqrt{{x^2+\frac 1 n}}$$

Answer (score 5):

> No. This function is not even differentiable at $0$, while power series give us functions that are infinitely differentiable within their interval of convergence.

– Andres Caicedo, Apr 24 at 0:55

Answer (score 3):

A more algebraic way to see that there is no such power series is to consider its square $f(x)^2$, which must be equal to $x^2$. Even in the ring of formal power series (which is an integral domain) there are only two sqaure roots of the power series $x^2$, namely $x$ and $-x$; these obviously don't qualify.